# Point-to-Point MPC with differnt end time possible?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, optimal-control, discrete-optimization

I would like to use MPC to realise the transition from one state (incl. position, speed and accleration) to another state with different end time.  But I have no reference trajectory, what I know only initial condition and final condition. so my question is:
 1. Could MPC help solve this problem?  (final state is not equals to zero), add terminal constraint?
 2. I would like to use MPC to generate trajectories with different end time, which means I want to reach the desired state with differnt end time. In MPC,  $T_{end}=kT_{s}$, $k=N_p$, should I change the value of $T_s$ or change the value of $N_p$?

Comment: What kind of solver are you using? Namely, if it is a general [quadratic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming) solver one usually can already add those, otherwise [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) could be an option.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen  I'm using QP solver now, cause it's more easy to handle the constraint. One more question, for different end time, do you think it's a good idea to change the value of Np?

Comment: If I have understood correctly, you need to estimate the future reference. In google, search for the exact therm to see the publication: "Future Reference Prediction in Model Predictive Control based Driving Simulators"